Philosophy of applying Faltings' product theorem
Faltings' product theorem says that on $\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{P}^{n_1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{P}^{n_m}$ over $k$ of characteristic $0$. For $\epsilon>0$, $d_1> \cdots >d_m$ decrease rapidly and $f \in \Gamma(\mathbb{P},\mathscr{O}(d_1,\ldots, d_m))$, suppose that for some $\sigma >0$, $Z$ is an irreducible component of both $Z_{\sigma}$ and $Z_{\sigma+\epsilon}$ (Z_{\sigma} is the set of points where the index of $f$ is $\geq \sigma$), then $Z$ is a product of closed subvarieties $Z_i$ of $\mathbb{P}^{n_i}$, also $\deg Z_i$ are bounded only depending on $\epsilon$.
Bombieri-Gubler has the following explaination of how to apply the product theorem (it is a little expansion of Faltings' original remark):
Let $N > \dim \mathbb{P}$ be an integer and let $\sigma >0$. Assume the index at $x \in \mathbb{P}$ is $\geq \sigma$. Consider a chain
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P} \neq Z_1 \supset Z_2 \supset \cdots \supset Z_N \ni x
\end{equation}
where $Z_i$ is an irreducible component of $Z_{i\sigma/N}$. Then we eventually arrive for some $i$, $Z_i=Z_{i+1}$. Taking $\epsilon=\sigma/N$, apply the product theorem and obtain
\begin{equation}
Z_i=Z_{i1} \times \cdots \times Z_{im}.
\end{equation}
Then there must exits some $l$ such that $Z_{il} \neq \mathbb{P}^{n_l}$. Then they claims: the study of vanishing of $f$ on $Z_i$ is reduced, by projecting to some linear subspace of $\mathbb{P}^{n_l}$, to the study of vanishing in a multiprojective space with smaller dimension than $\mathbb{P}$. Then apply the induction.
Since $Z_{il}$ is not necessarily linear, why could we do the projection to a linear subspace? I believe they don't mean $Z_{il}$ is linear, then how does this reduction work (more explicitly)?
